Tracing the source of an app crash
I have a KVM node (via proxmox)  Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 0 @ 3.20GHz x 4 /16GB and I'm trying to run an app but it INSTANTLY crashes. It used to run just fine until a week ago it just began crashing with no changes made anywhere. I SUSPECT it might me memory allocation issues but I'm not 100% sure and I'd be grateful if you can help me read strace/gdb data:
GDB: https://pastebin.com/raw/JYcMvNU8
Strace: https://paste.gg/p/anonymous/9f4a0247859e4f60a17c321fe783c28b/files/23f7e49b252449d8909a1a363e4b1660/raw
GBD seems useless, but in strace I see:
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio", O_RDONLY) = 19
but not sure if it is relevant or just usual stuff
